# printing out difference of two arrays

Tags: java

**It is now prinitng internsection correctly but not difference!**

```
public class setPractice {
public static Scanner kbd;

public static final int MAXSIZE = 20;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    int sizeA, sizeB, interSize, diffSize;
    int[] setA;
    int[] setB;
    //int[] intersect;
    int[] difference =  new int[MAXSIZE] ;
    //int[] resultSet =  new int[MAXSIZE]; 

    System.out.print("How many numbers will be in the 1st set: ");
    sizeA = kbd.nextInt();
    while (sizeA > MAXSIZE) {
        System.out
                .print("Error: Set size is too large. Re-enter set size: ");
        sizeA = kbd.nextInt();
    }
    setA = new int[sizeA];
    System.out.println("Enter list of integers for 1st set: ");
    getData(setA, sizeA);
    sort(setA, sizeA);
    System.out.println("The ascending order for 1st is:");
    print(setA, sizeA);


    System.out.println("How many numbers will be in the 2nd set: ");
    sizeB = kbd.nextInt();
    while (sizeB > MAXSIZE) {
        System.out
                .print("Error: Set size is too large. Re-enter set size: ");
        sizeB = kbd.nextInt();
    }
    setB = new int[sizeB];
    System.out.println("Enter list of integers for 2nd set: ");
    getData(setB, sizeB);
    sort(setB, sizeB);
    System.out.println("The ascending order for the 2nd set  is:");
    print(setB, sizeB);

    int[] resultSet = new int[sizeA +sizeB]; 
    interSize = intersection(setA, setB, sizeA, sizeB, resultSet);
    System.out.println("The intersection of the two sets is: ");
    for (int x = 0; x < interSize; x++) {
        System.out.println(resultSet[x] + " ");
    }

    diffSize = difference(setA, sizeA, setB, sizeB, resultSet);
    System.out.println("The difference of A-B is: ");
    for (int x = 0; x < diffSize; x++) {
        System.out.print(resultSet[x] + " ");
    }
}

public static void getData(int[] set, int size) {

    for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
        int num = kbd.nextInt();
        int count = search(set, size, num);
        if (count == 0)
            set[x] = num;
        else
            x--;
    }
}

public static int search(int[] set, int size, int num) {

    int count = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
        if (num == set[x])
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}

public static int difference(int[] setA, int sizeA, int[] setB, int sizeB,
        int[] resultSet) {
        int count = 0;
        boolean flag = true;
        for(int i = 0; i<sizeA ; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<sizeB ; j++){
                if(setA[i] == setB[j]){
                    flag =false;
                    break;
                }
                if(flag){
                    resultSet[count++] =setA[i];
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
}

public static void sort(int[] nums, int size) {
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size - i - 1; j++) {
            if (nums[j] > nums[j + 1]) {
                temp = nums[j];
                nums[j] = nums[j + 1];
                nums[j + 1] = temp;

            }
        }
    }

}

public static void print(int[] nums, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        //if (nums[i] != 0) {
            System.out.println(nums[i]);
        //}
    }
}

public static int intersection(int[] setA, int[] setB, int sizeA,
        int sizeB, int[] resultSet) {
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <sizeA ; i++){
        for(int j=0; j< sizeB ; j++){
            if(setA[i] == setB[j]){
                resultSet[count++]=setA[i];
                break; 
            }
        }
    }
    return count;

}
```

}

How many numbers will be in the 1st set: 4

Enter list of integers for 1st set: 
11
2
3
56

The ascending order for 1st is:
2
3
11
56

How many numbers will be in the 2nd set: 
5

Enter list of integers for 2nd set: 
56
3
33
98
87

The ascending order for the 2nd set  is:
3
33
56
87
98

The intersection of the two sets is: 
3 
56

The difference of A-B is: 
0 0 0 0 0

**The methods used were given to us with those parameters-our job was to code the methods
using the parameters given**

Comment: It would be better to show us the complete program with the input.

Comment: In Java an array has a `length` attribute. No need to pass the size.

Comment: The method was given to us with those parameters and we had to code it to find the intersection of the two arrays!

Comment: Add examples of your inputs that cause this result.

Comment: I added the complete program as well as the input I gave to the program

Comment: @user3546001 in your `print` method, why this: `if (nums[i] != 0) {...}` ?

Comment: So it only prints out the numbers in the array that are input by the user and not the other index of the array that are not filled. Any suggestions on how to improve on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed around some things. But the good new is your code is working just fine. Your arrays are just filled with unnecessary zeros

for an example in your case

```
setA = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,3,12}
setB = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,6}
```

So what i changed is this

```
int[] setA; //from int[] setA = new int[MAXSIZE];
int[] setB; //from int[] setB = new int[MAXSIZE];
```

and set your array size when the user inputs it after your

```
while(sizeA > MAXSIZE)
```

loop

```
setA = new int[sizeA];
```

This made your Intersection work but not the difference. For me it shows 0 as a difference.

EDIT:
after you print setb

```
print(setB, sizeB);
```

i also set all the other array to the max of setA and setB

```
intersect = new int[Math.max(sizeA, sizeB)];
difference = new int[Math.max(sizeA, sizeB)];
resultSet = new int[Math.max(sizeA, sizeB)];
```

as well as on top doing this

```
int[] intersect; //from int[] intersect = new int[MAXSIZE];
int[] difference;//from int[] difference = new int[MAXSIZE];
int[] resultSet; //from int[] resultSet = new int[MAXSIZE];
```

custom max method:

```
pubic static int Max(int num1, int num2){
    if(num1 > num2){
        return num1;
    }else{
        return num2;
    }
}
```

Add this in your code so you can see any array content at any given time:

```
public static void printArray(int[] array){
    for(int i: array){
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

FINAL EDIT:

your difference method needs quite a bit of work but it got worked out. Messy but it works. I'd redo your program differently but i just tried fixing what you have.

```
public static int difference(int[] setA, int sizeA, int[] setB, int sizeB,
         int[] resultSet) {
    int count = 0;
    boolean flag = true;
    for(int i = 0; i<sizeA ; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<sizeB ; j++){
            if(setA[i] == setB[j]){
                flag =false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag){
            resultSet[count++] =setA[i];
        }
        flag = true;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<sizeB ; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<count; j++){
            if(setB[i] == resultSet[j]){
                flag =false;
                break;
            }
        }
        for(int j = 0; j<sizeA ; j++){
            if(setB[i] == setA[j]){
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag){
            resultSet[count++] =setB[i];
        }
        flag = true;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: So i should put  'setA = new int[sizeA]' after the while statement?

Comment: So i changed my code according to your suggestion and now it is printing out the sort method correctly but the intersection is still printing "0 0 0"

Comment: Forgot to mentioned i did this too... look at edit when i update it.

Comment: the Math.max method sets it equal to the maximum! Is there another way to do it without using the Math.max method?

Comment: make your own max method... public static int max(int num1, int num2)... and use an if then statement to see which one is greater then one anthor and return the higher number of the 2

Comment: The math max method is giving me an out of bound error but i thought setting the interesect, difference, and resultSet to maxsize would do the same thing?

Comment: or could i use an add function like:  new int [] = new int[sizeA+sizeB]

Comment: The reason I did the max(x,y) is to get rid of the zeros from the arrays. And you are not going to loop it 20 times for 4 numbers doing this way.

Comment: So i changed my code to your suggestion except the math.max method because the instructor does not want us using that. It is correctly printing out the intersection but do you see any problem areas in it?thank you!

Comment: Im trying to work out difference. So far it displays 12 but not the 1

Comment: View the final edit to see how to make difference work, as well.

Comment: Thank you so much! You have truly been a life saver for me in this :)Just to understand the logic behind the rest of the method: `for(int i = 0; i<sizeB ; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<count; j++){
            if(setB[i] == resultSet[j]){
                flag =false;
                break;
            }
        }
        for(int j = 0; j<sizeA ; j++){
            if(setB[i] == setA[j]){
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag){
            resultSet[count++] =setB[i];
        }
        flag = true;
    }

    return count;

Comment: Why did you add two additional loops? Just want to understand the logic

Comment: Sorry i had to go out for a bit. Well the 2 loops on the bottom is to use setB as the main array to compare. First it is checking if anything from setB is in resultSet and if there is then set flag false. Else if anything in setB is in setA then set flag false. IF setB is not in resultSet AND setA then add that to the resultSet as a number that does not have any similarity between setA and setB.

Answer (score 0):

First recommendation, do not invent hot water :). Move your data into sets and use existing tools for the job: [commons collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/index.html).

Comment: Probably OP's in learning phase and can't use any other tool. Otherwise, you would use `Set` for the job.

Comment: I have to use this method and not use any other existing tool! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

@user3546001 just comment out line/remove following condition

```
if (nums[i] != 0) in your print() function
```

you will get your answer why this code is not working...

if still confused just remove the sorting logic which is sorting your array and is putting 0 s first in your array.

thats why you are getting result as zero intersection....

i hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

@user2408578

Since the maxsize is 20 it is filling in the array at the end of it and printing out all 20 indexes including the ones that arent filled

I did that and now I am getting this

```
 Enter list of integers for 1st set: 
2
56
7
```

The ascending order for 1st is:

```
  0
  0
  0
  0
  0
  0
  0
  0
  0
  0
  0
  0
  0
  0
  0
  0
  0
  2
  7
 56
```